# How to avoid loading a specific column in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

In Linq-to-SQL, it's possible to get all data from an entity object via using the `ToList` method:

```
db.users.Tolist();
```

It is also possible to get multiple columns via the `select` method:

```
var users= db.users.Select(
                t => new
                {
                    t.c1,
                    t.c2,
                    t.c3,
                    .
                    .
                });
```

But I want to get all columns without one specific column like this:

```
db.users.exclude(t.c2).tolist();
```

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454745/linq-excluding-a-column.

Comment: you might be looking for the `[NotMapped]` attribute if all queries you do should exclude the column/property.

Comment: Sounds like a possible [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you explain why you want to do this? Maybe there is a better solution for your actual problem.

Comment: NotMapped attribute avoid to create my  column in a database

Comment: @AliBesharatinia can you explain why you are hiding some property from entity. Is it something like password/hash? And you are skipping it for security resons?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy  use [jqgrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) To Do dynamically crud operations ,But [jqgrid] Dosent Work With navigation Proerrty And Lazy loadin , i want  to avoid loading navigation Property in backend Cod

Comment: @Igor...........

Comment: Add `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` before your query. How are you returning the result? Is it serialized to json? If so you could also add [JsonIgnore] to the properties you do not want to serialize to the client (if you are using json.net which is the standard included library).

Comment: @Igor very thanks that's work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To Do dynamically crud operations , But [jqgrid] Doesn't Work With navigation Property And Lazy loading, I want to avoid loading navigation Property in backend Cod

Add `db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` before your query.

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.users.Tolist();
```

If there are collections you **do** want to load you would have to use [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
db.users.Incude(x => x.Roles).Tolist();
```

#### OR

If you are returning with json.net, which is the standard included library, add [JsonIgnore](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) to the properties you do not want to serialize to the client. Example:

```
public class User {
  [JsonIgnore]
  public ICollection UsersRoles {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to walk backwards?

Just select the columns you want and don't select the one you don't want

instead of selecting them all and excluding the one you don't want like you are doing here :

```
var users= db.users.Select(
                t => new
                {
                    t.c1,
                    t.c2,
                    t.c3,
                    .
                    .
                    .

                });
```

do this instead:

```
var users= from u in db.users

        select u.c1, u.c3, etc... ;  //Dont select what you don't want
```

Or this one would be ok too :

```
var users = from u in db.users

                select new 
                {
                    c1 = u.c1, 
                    c3 = u.c3
                }.ToList();
```